# Formula for marginal density of multivariate normal (Bayesian)?

Tags: probability, bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution

I would like to ask if anyone knows the formula for the marginal density of a multivariate normal. I could not find it anywhere.

Say, $x | \mu \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$

and $\pi(\mu) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \Sigma_0).$

What is $p(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start from 1D, and std normal $\mu$ for simplicity:$$\begin{align}p(x)&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(x|\mu)p(\mu)d\mu=\int_{-\infty}^\infty C e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}e^{-\mu^2/2}d\mu\\&=Ce^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x\mu/\sigma^2-(1/2\sigma^2+1)\mu^2}d\mu}_{\propto e^{-\alpha x^2}}\propto e^{-bx^2}\end{align}$$

So, $p(x)$ is normally distributed. Its mean and variance can be found via explicitly writing all the formulation, or via law of total variance, and total expectation, e.g. $E[X]=E[E[X|\mu]]=\mu_0$.

The algebra is similar, but cumbersome for multi dimensional case. Not explicitly same, but similar analysis can be found in the [wiki](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Normal_distribution#/With_known_variance) entry for normal distribution, in which you can take the likelihood function as if it has one sample. Results follow from self-conjugacy of normal distribution.

**Edit**: I've derived it:
$$\begin{align}p(x)&=\int p(x|\mu)p(\mu)d\mu\\&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n|\Sigma|^{1/2}|\Sigma_0|^{1/2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^T\Sigma^{-1}x+\mu_0^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu_0)}}_{C(x)}\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(-2\overbrace{(x^T\Sigma^{-1}+\mu_0^T\Sigma_0^{-1})}^{a^T}\mu+\mu^T\overbrace{(\Sigma^{-1}+\Sigma_0^{-1})}^b\mu}d\mu\end{align}$$
The inside of the integral can be made completed to normal PDF; let $m,S$ be mean and covariance matrix of a prototype normal RV. Then, the exponential term will look like the following: $\exp(-\frac{1}{2}(y^TS^{-1}y-2m^TS^{-1}y+m^TS^{-1}m))$. Matching the coefficients of the linear and quadratic term yields $m=Sa,S^{-1}=b$, and we need to add/subtract the term $m^Tbm$ to complete into square:
$$\begin{align}p(x)&=C(x)e^{\frac{1}{2}m^Tbm}\underbrace{\int e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\mu^Tb\mu-2a^T\mu+m^Tbm)}d\mu}_{(2\pi)^{n/2}|b|^{1/2}}\\&\underbrace{\propto}_{\text{after substitutions}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}x^T(\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}b^{-1}\Sigma^{-1})x-2x^T\Sigma^{-1}b^{-1}\Sigma_0^{-1}\mu_0\right)\end{align}$$

This is in Gaussian form, and we have $\Sigma_x^{-1}=\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}b^{-1}\Sigma^{-1}$, $\mu_x=\Sigma_x\Sigma^{-1}b^{-1}\Sigma_0^{-1}\mu_0$. Of course, this isn't the simplified version. Once we know that $p(x)$ is in normal form, we can calculate its mean and covariance with some other method and substitute in normal PDF. For example, as I've explained above, law of iterated expectations give $E[X]=\mu_0$. The total law of variance gives us that
$$\operatorname{var}(X)=\operatorname{var}(E[X|\mu])+E[\operatorname{var}(X|\mu)]=\operatorname{var}(\mu)+E[\Sigma]=\Sigma_0+\Sigma$$
Eventually, we find that $$X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0,\Sigma+\Sigma_0)$$
Without using expectation and variance laws, we'd have to go through several tedious steps involving matrix identities. For example, for the covariance, we'd do:
$$\begin{align}\Sigma_x&=(\Sigma^{-1}-\Sigma^{-1}(\Sigma^{-1}+\Sigma_0^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}\\&=(I-(\Sigma^{-1}+\Sigma_0^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma\\&=(I-(I+\Sigma\Sigma_0^{-1})^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma\\&=(I-\Sigma_0(\Sigma_0+\Sigma)^{-1})^{-1}\Sigma\\&=(\Sigma_0+\Sigma)((\Sigma_0+\Sigma)-\Sigma_0)^{-1}\Sigma\\&=(\Sigma_0+\Sigma)\Sigma^{-1}\Sigma\\&=\Sigma_0+\Sigma\end{align}$$

For the mean, we'd prove that $\Sigma_x\Sigma^{-1}b^{-1}\Sigma_0^{-1}=I$, but we don't need to do it since total law of variance and expectation provide the answers we need.

Comment: Thank you! I got the 1D case too. I was just not sure if there's a formula out there for higher dimension.